# Change table data on click - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in JavaScript. I am trying to program that present a table, and upon clicking on a cell it changes its content. this is what I tried to do:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    td {
      border: 3px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td onclick="this.value ='Change 1';">cell 1</td>
      <td onclick="this.value ='Change 2';">cell 2</td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`td` doesn't have `value` property, you need to use **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** or **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** instead

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    td {
      border: 3px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td onclick="this.innerHTML ='Change 1';">cell 1</td>
      <td onclick="this.innerHTML ='Change 2';">cell 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```